# How to rewrite Oracle merge into in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In Oracle, I can use `merge into` to select rows from one or more sources for update , like this:

```
merge into table_A A
using table_B B
on A.id = B.id 
when matched then update 
set A.name = B.name
```

Is there a way to get the same result using Pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas this is [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
df1=df1.set_index('id')
df1.update(df2.set_index('id'))
df1=df1.reset_index()
```

---

Sample data and output

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2],'name':['A','B']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,3],'name':['D','C']})
df1=df1.set_index('id')
df1.update(df2.set_index('id'))
df1
Out[58]: 
   name
id     
1     D
2     B
```

Comment: Very nice use of the proper API.